# Add javascript in head to wordpress plugin page via functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I wanted to add JavaScript in wordpress plugin page via functions.php
how i can do this

what i have tried

```
global $pagenow;
if (( $pagenow == 'admin.php' ) && ($_GET['page'] == 'booknetic')) {
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(window.location.href);
    jQuery(".fa-puzzle-piece").hide();
</script>
}
```

its working but its not adding javascript inside the body of the page its adding to the top of the page outside the html document.
so after this i tried this

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_test_init' );

function add_test_init() {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(window.location.href);
    jQuery(".fa-puzzle-piece").hide();
</script> ';
}
```

and this works on other pages but not on plugin page that i want
so is there any way to add javascript on plugin page?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use admin_enqueue_scripts hook instead of wp_head. Add the below PHP code to your child theme's functions.php. If not using a child theme, use get_template_directory_uri() instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_test_init' );
function add_test_init() {
    global $pagenow;
    if (( $pagenow == 'admin.php' ) && ($_GET['page'] == 'booknetic')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( "test-script", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/test-script.js', array('jquery'), false, false );
    }
}
```

Then you should create a jquery file named test-script.js inside your child theme in the directory of /assets/js/ and then add the below jquery code with no conflict rule.

```
(function( $ ) {
    console.log(window.location.href);
    $(".fa-puzzle-piece").hide();
})(jQuery);
```